# Case-Control Study Design for Longitudinal Analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, panel-data, observational-study, case-control-study

I am designing a study in which I want to examine the relationship between a disease - major depression - and five exposures of interest: healthy/unhealthy diet, daily exercise hours, general outlook on life, weight, and nightly sleep hours in a certain population. I would like to use a case-control design because it's flexible and will allow me to get an idea of the relationship between each of these exposures and the outcome. This is more of a hypothesis-generating study than a hypothesis-confirming study.

I have a population of approximately 2000 individuals who do not have the disease and 500 who do. The population is fairly widespread across the US. I was planning to enroll 200 cases (individuals with major depression) and 200 controls (individuals without major depression), matched on age and region in the US (I might add additional matching factors later, that isn't too important to my question right now).

From there, I plan on administering a survey of each of the exposures of interest over a period of time and using odds ratios to examine the difference between the exposures in subjects with and without the disease.

I'm just using this question as a sounding board to see if there are any major flaws in my study design. For a longitudinal, hypothesis-generating study with multiple exposures and one outcome a matched case-control design makes sense, right?